# AWS KMS python3.6 and boto3 example with AES CBC

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kms

I have tried to do an ecnryption demo using python 3.6 and boto3 with AWS KMS but it lacks the operational mode of AES. I wonder if you can point me in the direction of how to do this.

I have tried to define AES.CBC_MODE within the calling of the KeySpec but it only takes AES_256 or AES_128.

Here is the code:

```
import base64
import boto3

from Crypto.Cipher import AES


PAD = lambda s: s + (32 - len(s) % 32) * ' '


def get_arn(aws_data):
    return 'arn:aws:kms:{region}:{account_number}:key/{key_id}'.format(**aws_data)


def encrypt_data(aws_data, plaintext_message):
    kms_client = boto3.client(
        'kms',
        region_name=aws_data['region'],
        aws_access_key_id='your_key_id',
        aws_secret_access_key='your_secred_key_id')

    data_key = kms_client.generate_data_key(
        KeyId=aws_data['key_id'],
        KeySpec='AES_256')

    cipher_text_blob = data_key.get('CiphertextBlob')
    plaintext_key = data_key.get('Plaintext')

    # Note, does not use IV or specify mode... for demo purposes only.
    cypher = AES.new(plaintext_key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    encrypted_data = base64.b64encode(cypher.encrypt(PAD(plaintext_message)))

    # Need to preserve both of these data elements
    return encrypted_data, cipher_text_blob


def decrypt_data(aws_data, encrypted_data, cipher_text_blob):
    kms_client = boto3.client(
        'kms',
        region_name=aws_data['region'])

    decrypted_key = kms_client.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=cipher_text_blob).get('Plaintext')
    cypher = AES.new(decrypted_key)

    return cypher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encrypted_data)).rstrip()


def main():
    # Add your account number / region / KMS Key ID here.
    aws_data = {
        'region': 'us-east-1',
        'account_number': 'your_account',
        'key_id': 'your_key_id',
    }

    # And your super secret message to envelope encrypt...
    plaintext = 'Superduper and the mighty Scoop!'

    # Store encrypted_data & cipher_text_blob in your persistent storage. You will need them both later.
    encrypted_data, cipher_text_blob = encrypt_data(aws_data, plaintext)
    print(encrypted_data)

    # # Later on when you need to decrypt, get these from your persistent storage.
    decrypted_data = decrypt_data(aws_data, encrypted_data, cipher_text_blob)
    print(decrypted_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implementing your own envelope encryption, have you considered using the AWS Encryption SDK?[1][2] It integrates closely with AWS KMS and makes it simple to do secure envelope encryption, protecting your data keys with a KMS CMK. It also makes it simple to keep track of all the pieces you need for decryption (IV, encrypted data key, encryption context, etc) by giving you back a single ciphertext message that contains everything that the client needs to know in order to decrypt the message.

You can find an example of how to implement something similar to what you show in your question here[3].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html

[2] https://aws-encryption-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

[3] https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-python/blob/master/examples/src/basic_encryption.py